# excel_reader2.php - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /includes/excel_reader2.php on line 916

Tags: php, syntax-error, phpexcelreader

I am trying to access an excel file with excel_reader2.php include. But I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in >/home/user/public_html/includes/excel_reader2.php on line 916

This is line 916:

> function Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($file='',$store_extended_info=true,$outputEncoding='') {

and here is the line where I call it:

> $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("/home/user/public_html/Games/Games.xls",false);